# Help to connect in Reporting Web Services 2008 R2 with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, soap, reporting-services

I am trying using PHP with MSSQL Reporting Services, but without success... First, i tried using helloworld.php from SRSS SKD PHP, and returns this error:

Failed to connect to Reporting Service:

```
Make sure that the url (http://10.120.100.12/ReportServer/) and credentials are correct!
```

And trying using pure **SoapClient**:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://10.120.100.12/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx) [function.SoapClient-SoapClient]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\index.php on line 5

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [function.SoapClient-SoapClient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://10.120.100.12/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\index.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://10.120.100.12/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx' in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\index.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://10.120.1...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\index.php on line 5
```

- Have a extra IIS configuration to make?
- i am sure that use the same login and password used in web browser version. Need something more?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're passing username/password - in that case NTLM authentication might be the issue. I'd recommend trying to enable basic authenticaiton to see if the problem goes away: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx